# Clarification- Complements of a normal Hall Subgroup are Conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While reading through "Permutation Groups" by Donald S. Passman, I came across a proof explaining why for a finite group $G$ with a normal Hall subgroup $H$, if we let $G/H$ be solvable, any two complements of $H$ are solvable. I understand up till defining a group $V=E \cap HU$ such that $V\mathrel{\unlhd}H$ and $V\cong U$.

I don't understand why we define $V$ in such a way. The proof is written below.

Let $G/H$ be solvable and let $B$ and $E$ be complements for $H$.  We show that $B$ and $E$ are conjugate by induction on $|G|$. Let $U$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $B$. Since $B \cong G/H$ is solvable, U is a $p$-group for some prime $p$.  Set $V=E \cap HU$ such that $V\mathrel{\unlhd}E$ and $V\cong U$. Clearly, $U$ and $V$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $HU$ and hence there exists $g \in HU$ with $V^g=U$. Thus $U\mathrel{\unlhd}B$ and $U\mathrel{\unlhd}E^g$, and both $B$ and $E^g$ are complements for $H \cap N$ in $N$, where $N=\mathfrak{N}(U)$. Since, $B/U$ and $E^g/U$ are complements for $(H \cap N)U/U$ in $N/U$ and $|N/U|<|G|$, induction implies that $B/U$ and $E^g/U$ are conjugate in $N/U$. Hence, $B$ and $E^g$ are conjugate in $G$ and the result follows. $\square$

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/104041).

Comment: Thank you @Shaun, I have now transcribed the proof in TeX instead.

Comment: It should be $V \unlhd E$, not $V \unlhd H$. It is not clear to me what we are asking. We define $V$ that way, because that''s the way the proof works. If you don't understand the proof, then you need to say exactly which step you don't understand.

Comment: @DerekHolt, my confusion is stemming from not understanding the motivation behind $V$. While the following steps all make sense it seems like $V$ was "pulled out of thin air" and I would not be able to come up with this on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that, since $G/H$ is soluble, one can work up a series for $G/H$ whose terms are elementary abelian $p$-groups for various primes $p$. So the outline is:

---

Choose $B$ and $E$ complements to $H$ in $G$. Show that, by replacing $E$ with a conjugate, $B\cap E$ can be made non-trivial (and in fact $B\cap E$ contains a non-trivial subgroup normal in both $B$ and $E$).

---

Since $G/H$ is soluble, the only thing we really have are minimal normal subgroups, so let $U\leq B$ be such. Now, take the image of $U$ in $G/H$, which is $HU/H$. We have that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $E$ as well, so choose $V\leq H$ such that the image of $V$ in $G/H$ is the same as the image of $U$. This is $V=E\cap HU$. Then we can conjugate $E$ by some element $g\in G$ so that $V^g=U$. Replace $E$ by $E^g$ and $E\cap B\geq U$.